# Cannot convert value of type 'MyEnum<T.Type>' to expected argument type 'MyEnum<_>'

Tags: swift, unit-testing, generics

I have a network layer working with generics and I'm using protocols so I can test it later. I have followed this tutorial https://medium.com/thecocoapps/network-layer-in-swift-4-0-972bf2ea5033

This is my Mock for testing:

```
import Foundation
@testable import TraktTest

class MockUrlSessionProvider: ProviderProtocol {

    enum Mode {
        case success
        case empty
        case fail
    }

    private var mode: Mode

    init(mode: Mode) {
        self.mode = mode
    }

    func request<T>(type: T.Type, service: ServiceProtocol, completion: @escaping (NetworkResponse<T>) -> Void) where T: Decodable {                
        switch mode {
        case .success: completion(NetworkResponse.success(T))
        case .empty: completion(.failure(.noData))
        case .fail: completion(.failure(.unknown("Error")))
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error: `Cannot convert value of type 'NetworkResponse<T.Type>' to expected argument type 'NetworkResponse<_>'` in this line: completion(NetworkResponse.success(T))

If I send this to my completion success it compile: 
`try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data!)`
(dummy data that I created using encode and my model), but crash when get to my model because is nil despite I had encoded using JSONEncoder() with a correct model.

I think it works, because is the same logic that I use in my class that implements ProviderProtocol in my app:

```
final class URLSessionProvider: ProviderProtocol {

    private var session: URLSessionProtocol

    init(session: URLSessionProtocol = URLSession.shared) {
        self.session = session
    }

    func request<T>(type: T.Type, service: ServiceProtocol, completion: @escaping (NetworkResponse<T>) -> Void) where T: Decodable {
        let request = URLRequest(service: service)
        session.dataTask(request: request) { [weak self]  data, response, error in
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            self?.handleDataResponse(data: data, response: httpResponse, error: error, completion: completion)
        }.resume()
    }

    private func handleDataResponse<T: Decodable>(data: Data?, response: HTTPURLResponse?, error: Error?, completion: (NetworkResponse<T>) -> Void) {
        guard error == nil else { return completion(.failure(.unknown(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error"))) }
        guard let response = response else { return completion(.failure(.unknown("no_response".localized()))) }

        switch response.statusCode {
        case 200...299:
            guard let data = data, let model = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else { return completion(.failure(.noData)) }
            completion(.success(model))
        default: completion(.failure(.unknown("no_response".localized())))
        }
    }

}
```

URLSessionProtocol is just a protocol which has a method dataTask same as the one in URLSession.shared (receive a URLRequest and returns Data, Response and Error in a completion).

My Network responses are a couple of enums:

```
enum NetworkResponse<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(NetworkError)
}

enum NetworkError {
    case unknown(String)
    case noData
}
```

My provider protocol just have a function to make the request using generics:

```
protocol ProviderProtocol {
    func request<T>(type: T.Type, service: ServiceProtocol, completion: @escaping(NetworkResponse<T>) -> Void) where T: Decodable
}
```

I don't think I need to use ServiceProtocol in my test because is to setup the request with endpoint, headers, body, id, etc. But this is the protocol I created:

```
typealias Headers = [String: String]
typealias Parameters = [String: Any]

protocol ServiceProtocol {
    func baseURL() -> URL
    var path: String? { get }
    var id: String? { get }
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var task: Task { get }
    var headers: Headers? { get }
    var parametersEncoding: ParametersEncoding { get }
}

enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case get = "GET"
    case post = "POST"
}

enum Task {
    case requestPlain
    case requestParameters(Parameters)
}

enum ParametersEncoding {
    case url
    case json
}
```

In my app, I have a class that implement ProviderProtocol and use a URLSession.shared to make the dataTask when some viewModel call the request with the appropiate model.

I'm use to make test with protocols and a specific model, but with generics is showing me that error. How can I achieve to have a mock provider using generics so I can test any viewModel who make a call to network using different kinds of models (stubs).

Comment: How are `ServiceProtocol`, `NetworkResponse`, `ProviderProtocol` defined? Can you update the question with this information, so that it will get closer to a [mcve]?

Comment: One option would be to change the associated value of `success(T)` to `success(T?)` (assuming that the definition is similar to the one from the article) and then your completion would become `completion(.success(someObject as? T))` for a (decodable) object or `completion(.success(nil))` for no value.

Comment: @Cristik I update my question with the information you ask me. I think the problem is the wrong use of generics in my test.

Comment: @Alladinian I don't what use nil because in my app I would have to check if the model is not nil, It can't be an optional. If there is no model, it's a failure case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because `NetworkResponse` expects an instance of `T`, while the mock tries to provide the actual `T`.

So, you need to somehow provide an instance, however this cannot be generated by the mock as it doesn't have enough information about how to construct an instance.

I recommend injecting the success value from the outside, when creating the mock. You can do this either by making the mock class generic, or by making the `Mode` enum generic. Below is a sample implementation for the latter:

```swift
class MockUrlSessionProvider: ProviderProtocol {

    // making the enum generic, to support injecting the success value
    enum Mode<T> {
        case success(T)
        case empty
        case fail
    }

    // need to have this as `Any` to cover all possible T generic arguments
    private var mode: Any

    // however the initializer can be very specific
    init<T>(mode: Mode<T>) {
        self.mode = mode
    }

    func request<T>(type: T.Type, service: ServiceProtocol, completion: @escaping (NetworkResponse<T>) -> Void) where T: Decodable {
        // if the mock was not properly configured, do nothing
        guard let mode = mode as? Mode<T> else { return }
        // alternatively you force cast and have the unit test crash, this should help catching early configuration issues
        // let mode = mode as! Mode<T>

        switch mode {
        case let .success(value): completion(NetworkResponse.success(value))
        case .empty: completion(.failure(.noData))
        case .fail: completion(.failure(.unknown("Error")))
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Cristik! injecting the model with the enum totally work!